# How show one element of the JSON on interpolation with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How show one element of the JSON on interpolation with Angular

```
  public responseData:any;

  renderTokenCard(){
    this.mundipaggS.checkToken().subscribe((response:any)=> {
    console.log("success: ", JSON.stringify(response));
    this.cartS.tokenCard = response;
    this.responseData = response;
  }, );
```

```html
    <div class="card-body">
    <i class="fab fa-cc-visa "></i>
       <div class="card-text">
         <b>{{responseData}}</b>
        </div
    </div>
```

The JSON

```json
[{"id":1,"pessoa_id":75505,"created_at":"2022-02-01T17:42:46.000000Z","holder":"test ","validade":"2026-06-01","bandeira":"Mastercard"}]
```

How can I show the JSON holder property for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

sould be pretty simple if I understand you correctly:

```js
this.responseData = response?[0];
```

```html
<!-- the whole responseData -->
<b>{{responseData | json}}</b>


<!-- only the holder property -->
<b *ngIf="responseData">{{responseData.holder}}</b>
```

Comment: so it shows all the json content, I wanted it to show only the "holder" property

Comment: a solution I found was this {{responseData[0]?.holder}}
but returns this error on console 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: ok, I updated my original answer

Comment: cool, that works too, but if I have any other json that is not at position 0, would there be a way to do it smarter?

Comment: this way I would have to create several variables, in case some other object is not in position 0

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, you can use interpolation to display it in HTML.

```html
<div class="card-body">
<i class="fab fa-cc-visa "></i>
//ngIf to check if responseData is not undefined, otherwise it will throw error
   <div class="card-text" *ngIf="responseData && responseData[0]">
     <b> {{responseData[0].holder }} </b>
    </div>
</div>
```

I see you are returning an array of objects, If you want to show multiple holders, you can use *ngFor to display them

```html
<div class="card-body">
<i class="fab fa-cc-visa "></i>
   <div class="card-text" *ngFor="let data of responseData">
     <b> {{data.holder }} </b>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I have another json, with another "holder", the way you did can work?

Comment: If another JSON is coming from another response then you should have another variable for it. If the response in this is multiple arrays instead of one [0] the loop will work. Could you share the use case you are thinking about ?

Comment: cool, this works, but it returns this error in the console
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: Try, `*ngIf="responseData && responseData[0]"`. The responseData might be undefined.

Comment: On the component.ts wouldn't you need to change something?

Comment: I have 3 arrays, one with position 0,1,2, would you be able to differentiate each one?

Comment: Can you show me all the `array` data?